# Java Virtual Machines deleted

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I accidently deleted the Java Virtual Machines folder, via terminal?  I have checked the trash, I can't find it there.

Is there anyway to bring it back?

I need that folder back for my intellJ to work

I've checked trash folder, and looked around online to reinstall java, but nothing seems to bring the folder back.
The directory it used to be in is /Library/Java/Java Virtual Machine

Comment: Just ... install it again? The same way you installed it initially? Note that IDEA itself comes with its own copy and doesn't depend on an external JVM to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

- Just **install a fresh JDK**. Then configure your project to use that JDK.
- *IntelliJ* contains its own JDK to run itself.
- *IntelliJ* can download and install a JDK from any of multiple vendors, for use by your project.
- I recommend instead using *SDKMAN!* utility for more serious work.

## Just install a fresh JDK

You said:

> I accidently deleted the Java Virtual Machines folder, via terminal?

- On a Mac, if you deleted with the [*Finder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) app, the files will be in the [Trash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_(computing)). To retrieve, drag from the *Trash* folder ️.
- If you deleted with the [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) in a console such as the [*Terminal*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) app, then the files are gone, poof . No way to retrieve, short of hacking the computer storage as done by [data rescue recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_recovery) experts.

But don’t panic; not a big problem.

Simply install a new [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) from your choice of vendor.

Vendors include, in no particular order: BellSoft, Microsoft, Amazon, Oracle, Red Hat, IBM, SAP, [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/), Azul Systems, and more.

Most of the JDK products across those vendors are based largely, if not entirely, on the source code developed at the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project. Some JDK products are free of cost, some are commercial products. Be sure to study the license terms of any JDK you obtain.

## *IntelliJ* IDE

You said:

> I need that folder back for my intellJ to work

That is not quite true.

Your installation of the IntelliJ [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) comes bundled with its own copy of a JDK. So [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) can boot and run on its own. IntelliJ itself does *not* require an external JDK.

You *do* need to specify an external JDK for *your* app to build and run. Select `File | Project Structure | Platform Settings | SDKs`. [See IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html).

1. Obtain a JDK from a vendor.
2. Install that JDK.
3. In your IntelliJ project, specify that you want your app to be built with, and run on, that particular JDK.

Tips:

- Recent versions of IntelliJ offer a convenience feature to both download and install a JDK from a subset of the vendors listed above. See [*Download a JDK*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/download-jdk/) by Helen Scott of JetBrains. And [see the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#supported-sdks).
- I am currently using the [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) utility on my Mac to install and remove JDK products. This slick kit of shell scripts works in Unix-oriented environments. SDKMAN! offers JDK products from any vendor that chooses to report their offerings to the SDKMAN! database.
- If you've no affinity for any particular vendor, I suggest starting with [*Adoptium*](https://adoptium.net/), a project at the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation) supported by several other JDK vendors.